# What are other sayings or expressions for "I can't wrap my head around"?

Tags: expressions, idioms

What are other idioms or expressions for the phrase "I can't wrap my head around"?.

In context:

"But what I still can't wrap my head around is why she behaved like that"

Comment: (Can't) comprehend, deduce, understand, etc.

Comment: *What still baffles me is...*; What still astonishes me is...*, *What is beyond me is...*, etc.

Comment: "scratch my head", "rack my brain", "beat my brain out", rarer "wear out the grey matter".

Comment: _I just can't fathom it._ _It's all double dutch to me_

Comment: *nonplussed, flummoxed, bewildered* would perhaps be some single words.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it.

Answer (score 5):

You can ***get or wrap your head, [mind](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+mind+around),  or [arms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+arms+around)***  around problems (often unsuccessfully):

> - The oldest of these expressions appears to be to “get one’s head around” something, a usage that the Oxford English Dictionary has been tracking since the 1920s.
> - The OED defines the expression and its variants as “to master or fully comprehend (a subject or fact), esp. despite initial difficulty or reluctance” or “to come to terms with (a situation).”

([grammophobia.com](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2014/10/head-2.html))

***[Get your head around something](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+head+around) :***

> - (informal)
>     to be able to understand something (usually negative):
>
>   - *He's tried to explain the rules of the game dozens of times but I just can't get my head around them.*

(Cambridge Idioms Dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

One of my favorites is "bake my noodle."

In your example:

"But what still bakes my noodle is why she behaved like that."

Comment: But that means something different.  Here you are saying, “what annoys me, makes me mad etc.”. Which is completely different from what confuses or confounds me.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not tasting what you’re basting.

I’m not picking up... what you’re putting down.

Inconceivable!

Comment: I actually read this as two possible expressions provided as answers to the question. If that is the case, I would suggest that the OP put both sentences in quotes for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not following you. Can you be clearer. It’s beyond me.